# Evento Tracking Google Tag Manager

Tags: jquery

Criei o evento no Google tag manager, e preciso trazer o valor que consta na ID clicada. Mas no Analytics ele mostra como 'undefined', alguém tem alguma dica?

```
$('a#HomeB02').on('click', function() {

  var Id_ = $(this).attr('id');

  dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'HomeB',
      'gaEventCategory': 'Home',
      'gaEventAction': 'Banner',
      'gaEventLabel': Id_

  });
});
```

Comment: Já experimentou colocar `console.log(Id_)` pra ver se lá aparece `undefined` também? Além disso, você pode escrever simplesmente `this.id` no lugar de `$(this).attr('id')`. O que `console.log(this)` imprime? Eu chutaria que o contexto do seu handler não é o que você espera que ele seja.

Comment: Testei e não funciona também, acredito que funciona apenas definindo diretamente no gaEventLabel. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @ctgPi consegui resolver.

Answer (score 1):

O tag manager por padrão não reconhece seletor de Jquery, um solução prática é coloca o snippet code padrão como HTML personalizado e coloca o código abaixo como personalizado e não se esqueça de ter Jquery code na página.

```
$('a#HomeB02').on('click', function() {

      var Id_ = $(this).attr('id');

      ga.push('send','event','Home','Banner', ''+Id_+'');

    });
```

Uma segunda solução é usar o event listener do Javascript ou do próprio tag manager.